# Advice on the free and stable react library for creating grid and tabular data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, grid

I am very new to ReactJs, we are developing a reactjs UI with tabular data with check boxes and drop down and editable links to popup a modal for editing and columns.
can anybody advice me on the best and stable library for creating Table.

Since we are new to React, it would be great if it has good documentation.

Below are some of them noticed while searching

1, https://www.ag-grid.com/
2, https://react-table.tanstack.com/

Thanks,

Have nice day ahead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are very new to React, [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/) might become overwhelming with the amount of customizability and extensibility it offers. It would be easy to render a simple table following the guides but you would probably need a decent enough understanding of React Hooks to implement the custom functionality you want.

If you are short on time, building a custom component which renders a CSS Grid layout might be faster than using a full blown library. You can use [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) to render your checkboxes, dropdowns and editable links.